# jquery - Input value doesn't seem to submit in IE

Tags: php, jquery, forms, internet-explorer

I have a Calendar page which allows the user to create tasks and also update them. When he click on the update button, the button triggers the submission of a form which submits the taskid to another page. On that page I query the database, and pre-fill the input values. Everything works in Chrome and Firefox but in IE, the form seems to submit as it redirects to the update page but the update page does get the post input value. Code below:

Form:

```
<form id="update-task-form-'.$row["taskid"].'" style="display: none;" action="../update-task/" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="recordToUpdate" id="recordToUpdate" value="'.$row["taskid"].'"/></form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("body").on("click", ".update-button", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var clickedID = this.id.split('-');
var DbNumberID = clickedID[1];

$("#update-task-form-" + DbNumberID).submit();

});
```

On the new page I have:

```
if (isset($_POST["recordToUpdate"])) {

$idToUpdate = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'recordToUpdate', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

more code

}
```

I've tried a number of things like appending the form to body or adding a submit button, but none worked in IE.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you.

EDIT 1:

```
        <tr id="task-'.$row["taskid"].'">

        <form id="update-task-form-'.$row["taskid"].'" style="display: none;" action="../update-task/" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="recordToUpdate" id="recordToUpdate" value="'.$row["taskid"].'"/>
        <input type="submit" name="recordToUpdate1" id="recordToUpdate1" value="Submit"/>
        </form>


        </tr>
```

Comment: First thing that crosses my mind when something like this isn't working in IE is is all the html valid? IE can be more finicky than other browsers with invalid html. Try checking the value from browser console before submitting. Also are any errors thrown in console in IE?

Comment: simple way to check is run the page through the w3c validator

Comment: I think the reason might be that the form is between <tr> tags, but of course it's hidden. But it seems like IE has a problem with that. I've updated the post with more code. Does anyone have any idea how I can bypass this?

Comment: That would defintiely do it. I don't see any `<td>` though either. Can you wrap form around the whole table?

Comment: It's wrapped in a <tr> and below it there are a few <td> but I haven't posted them.

Comment: Well it can't be a direct child of `<tr>`, that's invalid

Comment: I moved it and now it works. Fixed!